# RESTEazy and text answer for @Valid error instead JSON

Tags: java, json, validation, jax-rs, resteasy

I use in my project EJB and RESTEazy. I have fallowing method:

```
boolean save(@Valid Data data);
```

in response I get status 400 and body:

```
[PARAMETER]
[save.arg0.xyz]
[xyz must be 13 characters length and contains only letters and digits]
[AASSVV1234]
```

Why I don't get JSON?

My endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("save")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response save( ....
```

When everything is ok, I get 200 response and JSON in body.
I have defined ExceptionMapper and is registred.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using and in what container?